# How can I repeat my ringtone and increase the delay until a caller is sent to voicemail?

Tags: ios, iphone, ringtones, voicemail

I have a custom ringtone (30 seconds in length), but it goes to voicemail after approximately 20 seconds. Can I repeat the ringtone multiple times before redirecting the caller to voicemail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to talk to your phone service provider.  They can set the "delay before divert to voicemail", or provide you with a magic number to dial so you can set the delay.

I know my provider only allows a maximum of 25 seconds, which I agree is too short.